# Add a Rank column to MultiIndex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I like to add a `RANK` column to a MultiIndex DataFrame.

The DataFrame has three levels (`latitude`, `longitude` and `time`) and two columns (`FFDI` and `REF_ID`). It looks like:

```
                                    FFDI        REF_ID
latitude    longitude   time        
-39.20000   140.80000   1991-04-21  4.10000     0
                        1972-04-21  4.00000     0
                        1972-04-09  3.70000     0
                        1972-05-14  3.60000     0
                        1972-03-11  3.50000     0
            140.83786   1972-04-21  4.20000     1
                        1991-04-21  4.10000     1
                        1972-04-09  3.70000     1
                        1972-05-14  3.70000     1
                        1972-03-11  3.50000     1
            140.87572   1972-04-21  4.20000     2
                        1991-04-21  4.10000     2
                        1972-05-14  3.70000     2
                        1972-04-09  3.60000     2
                        1972-03-11  3.50000     2
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
-33.90000   149.92429   1972-12-23  30.80000    36109
                        1972-12-22  25.90000    36109
                        1991-03-19  22.60000    36109
                        1972-12-24  21.40000    36109
                        1972-09-22  20.00000    36109
            149.96214   1972-12-23  31.60000    36110
                        1972-12-22  26.40000    36110
                        1991-03-19  22.20000    36110
                        1972-12-24  22.10000    36110
                        1972-09-22  20.50000    36110
            150.00000   1972-12-23  33.60000    36111
                        1972-12-22  27.90000    36111
                        1972-12-24  23.60000    36111
                        1991-03-19  23.10000    36111
                        1972-09-22  21.20000    36111

180560 rows × 2 columns
```

I would like to add a new column called `RANK` and this will show ranking of `FFDI` for each latitude and longitude pair (e.g. largest FFDI on top). So the result will look like:

```
                                    FFDI        REF_ID      RANK
latitude    longitude   time        
-39.20000   140.80000   1991-04-21  4.10000     0           1
                        1972-04-21  4.00000     0           2
                        1972-04-09  3.70000     0           3
                        1972-05-14  3.60000     0           4
                        1972-03-11  3.50000     0           5
            140.83786   1972-04-21  4.20000     1           1
                        1991-04-21  4.10000     1           2
                        1972-04-09  3.70000     1           3
                        1972-05-14  3.70000     1           4
                        1972-03-11  3.50000     1           5
            140.87572   1972-04-21  4.20000     2           1
                        1991-04-21  4.10000     2           2
                        1972-05-14  3.70000     2           3
                        1972-04-09  3.60000     2           4
                        1972-03-11  3.50000     2           5
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
-33.90000   149.92429   1972-12-23  30.80000    36109       1
                        1972-12-22  25.90000    36109       2
                        1991-03-19  22.60000    36109       3
                        1972-12-24  21.40000    36109       4
                        1972-09-22  20.00000    36109       5
            149.96214   1972-12-23  31.60000    36110       1
                        1972-12-22  26.40000    36110       2
                        1991-03-19  22.20000    36110       3
                        1972-12-24  22.10000    36110       4
                        1972-09-22  20.50000    36110       5
            150.00000   1972-12-23  33.60000    36111       1
                        1972-12-22  27.90000    36111       2
                        1972-12-24  23.60000    36111       3
                        1991-03-19  23.10000    36111       4
                        1972-09-22  21.20000    36111       5

180560 rows × 2 columns
```

**Edit: where there are same repeated FFDI values on multiple days, ranking will be based on date in ascending order.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby()`:

```
df['RANK'] = df.groupby(['latitude','longitude'])['FFDI'].rank(ascending=False)
```

---

**Update** per comment, you can try:

```
df['RANK'] = (df.sort_values(['FFDI','Time'], ascending=[False,True])
                .groupby(['latitude','longitude']).cumcount() + 1
             )
```

You can also try to pass `method='first'` to `rank` on the original answer, given the `Time` is sorted.

Comment: Sorry. I realised there was an issue that is, if there are multiple same FFDI values for multiple days, ranking should be based on the date on ascending order. Any thoughts?

Comment: @alextc see the updated answer. You can play with the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I tried "df['RANK'] = df.groupby(['latitude','longitude'])['FFDI'].rank(ascending=False, method='first').astype(np.int32)"